# Returning a Partial View with Ajax MVC 5

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc

I've been wracking my head trying to figure out how this is working, or not as the case is.

I have an Ajax call to my HomeController:

```
function addPerson() {

    $.ajax({
        dataType: "html",
        url: '@Url.Action("AddPerson")',
        success: function (data) {
            $('#Detail').hide();
            $('#Detail').html(data);
        },
        error: function () {
            $('#Detail').html("<h3>Couldn't do that</h3>");
        }
    }
    );
```

With this ActionResult in my HomeController:

```
    public ActionResult AddPerson()
    {
        return PartialView("_AddPerson");
    }
```

_AddPerson.cshtml is in my Views/Shared folder as any partial view would be.

All I'm trying to do is append the html in the partial view to a div in my main view. Intelisense picks up on the AddPerson action but when I go to run it I get this error in Chrome when the function is called:

"Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) http://localhost:45003/Home/AddPerson"

I've actually got this call working previously with the only difference being I was passing data to the controller to do something other than just returning the partial view as is. Am I doing something wrong or is the functionality I'm trying to achieve not even possible?

Edit: My RouteConfig if it matters:

```
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
```

Comment: I don't normally pass a string to `View()` nor `PartialView()` as I prefer to the the ViewEngine figure out the name of the view.  In your case you have a view named `_Addperson.cshtml` ?

Comment: Yeah, I do. It's in the Shared folder rather than the Home folder, but in my working call that's not an issue so I really don't know how that would cause it. The Ajax call just fails and defaults to the error function, the ActionResult is never called. I don't for the life of me know why.

Comment: What is the `type` of `$.ajax`? Default is `GET`. I think you have decorated your action with `HttpPost`

Comment: So you're `AddPerson()` method is on the `HomeController` and you haven't edited the default route table, and you don't have any authorization in place?

Comment: /Home/AddPerson, whereas the the actual view is in /Shared/_AddPerson. Again I have an Ajax call that's very similar that works just fine so I don't really understand either why that one works or why this one doesn't.

Edit: Hmm, the routing might be what I'm missing alright. I'm new to MVC, to say the least. There is not auth at all as it stands

Comment: Check your routes. Or show them here.

Comment: `public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
        }`

That's literally all that's in my RouteConfig. I grasp the concept of the routing but getting it to do what I want is a different matter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just in case anyone finds this and encountered a similar problem to mine, I solved it by creating a new project and putting the exact same code into it. It works as intended.

I don't profess to know what caused the error in the original project but it may help solve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

It should work like a charm. Check the generated url from `@Url.Action("AddPerson")`. Are you sure you are in same route with the controller that defines `AddPerson`? You may have to add controller parameter to `Url.Action` or even area name.

```
url: '@Url.Action("AddPerson", "controllerName"'
```

or

```
url: '@Url.Action("AddPerson", "controllerName", new { area = "areaName" })'
```

Comment: I tried both but to no avail. This is my RouteConfig:

`public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes) { routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}"); routes.MapRoute( name: "Default", url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}", defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } ); }`

AddPerson is definitely in the HomeController so I'm a little lost as to what's wrong.

Comment: @user2966419 didn't you decorate `AddPerson` with any kind of attributes? Like the `HttpPost` one?

Comment: @user2966419 please do not update your question by comments, click edit on the question add add relevant information there.

Comment: @Javad_Amiry I have tried that. The default behavior without any decoration works in a separate project (the difference being I'm passing an id and doing some processing in the controller) I have so wonder if that would be causing it. As I said the Action method in my HomeController is never called - the error appears to be a wrong route but I can't for the life of me see where it's falling down.

Answer (score 0):

Using an AJAX call, you can use it the following way:

```
$('#Detail').load(
        '<%= Url.Action("AddPerson", "Home") %>'
 );
```